# unique id generator in a custom format in django

Tags: django, django-models

i want to generate an unique id code in my model
for example -

[id want to generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhnKM.png)

Can anyone Kindly help me in the same?
i Want id in the table as shown below-

```
class parameter(models.Model)
  name=models.models.CharField(max_length=50)
  type=model.#should come from another table
  subtype=model.#should come from another table 
  id= # should compile all the above as in picture
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not store the unique id in DB, because you can easily generate it by a property method:

```
class Parameter(models.Model)
  name=models.models.CharField(max_length=50)
  type=model.ForeignKey(Type)
  subtype=model.ForeignKey(SubType)
  product_type=model.ForeignKey(ProductType)
  serial_no = models.CharField()

  @property
  def generated_id(self):
      return '{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(self.type_id, self.subtype_id, self.product_type_id, self.serial_no.zfill(2))
```

If you intend to display it in [admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/), then simply try like this:

```
@admin.register(Parameter)
class ParameterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Parameter
    fields = ['type', 'sub_type', 'product_type', 'serial_no', 'generated_id']
    readonly_fields = ('generated_id',)
```

## Update

If you want to store in in DB, then you need to override the save method of the models. Like this:

```
class Parameter(models.Model)
  name=models.models.CharField(max_length=50)
  type=model.ForeignKey(Type)
  subtype=model.ForeignKey(SubType)
  product_type=model.ForeignKey(ProductType)
  serial_no = models.CharField()
  generated_id = models.CharField()

  def generate_id(self):
      return '{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(self.type_id, self.subtype_id, self.product_type_id, self.serial_no.zfill(2))

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.generated_id = self.generate_id()
     super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: if we generate with property method can we use it to filter or anywhere else in the software

Comment: You can use the property method anywhere as long as you can access the object. But it won't work with queryset. Hence filtering won't work. But as this unique id is being generated based on other fields, you can filter using those fields and ultimately find the object with that unique id

Comment: what should i go for if i want to store in database?

Comment: example we have 10 serial number later i deleted one . so now my generated id will also be changed right ? how can we avoid that

Comment: As long as you keep name, type, product type etc same, the generated id should be the same